# Ignore error row when update or insert SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, large-data

My project has to deal with huge database. At worst situation, it can be **more than 80 millions row.**

Now, I have 2 tables `T1` and `T2`. I have to copy data from table `T1` to table `T2`

- if a row in table `T1` already exists in table `T2` (same primary key), then update data of other columns of the row in `T1` to `T2`
- else insert new row into `T2`

At first, I use while loop to loop through 80 millions row in `T1` then update or insert to `T2`. This is very very very slow, it takes more than 10 hours to finish. But, if any row causes an error, I can ignore it and also catch the error.

After that, I use a query like:

```
update Table2 
set T2.Column1 = T1.Column1,T2.Column2=T1.Column2 
from Table2 T2 JOIN Table1 T1 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
```

This is much faster, only take about 1->2 hours to finish. But, if any row has an error, the query cannot execute at all.

So, my question is:

- Is there any way that above query can ignore error row and continue execute with valid row?
- If there is no way I can do that, what can I do to run faster than the first method and also can catch error row?

p/s: I have try to split the table to multiple small part then update or insert all small part in the same time, but it didn't faster at all.

I have solved the problem with my second method. I use TRY_CAST to prevent exception when insert or update row. Any data that invalid will be NULL. After finish, I compare 2 table and find different row. These row is error row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with my second method. I use TRY_CAST to prevent exception when insert or update row. Any data that invalid will be NULL. After finish, I compare 2 table and find different row. These row is error row.

Answer (score 0):

As for functionality you are asking for I would suggest the following:

```
MERGE INTO table2 target
USING
(
  SELECT id, column1, column2 FROM table1
) source ([id], [column1], [column2])
ON target.[Id] = source.[Id]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        target.Colum1 = source.Column1,
                target.COlumn2 = source.Column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Id], [Column1], [Column2])
    VALUES([Id], [Column1], [Column2])
;
```

As for ignoring errors - I see this way as a wrong one. in this regards I would invest some effort in data validation

Comment: Thank you. Running these got error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "SOURCE.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: Can you check if your select statement boudered in "unsing" works along. it can happen than the same error will be repeatet. If it will - than you should look for the issue in your SELECT

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the problem with my second method. I use TRY_CAST to prevent exception when insert or update row. Any data that invalid will be NULL. After finish, I compare 2 table and find different row. These row is error row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting existing rows from T2 and then Bulk Insert all rows from T1. It depends on the number of existing rows, if it is too large then this approach wouldn't work.